# get ObjectGUID (Active Directory) from OpenAM as String/Json

Tags: java, json, active-directory, openam

I have a short question. I use OpenAM to authenticate users against an Active Directory. The OpenAM is configured as an OAuth2 provider with a OAuth2 Client.

What I want is, to get the objectGUID of the user that is authenticated via the tokeninfo-endpoint. The OpenAM gets called from a Java/String application. I can retrieve the objectGUID already, when I set the scope, but the string is adulterated and looks something like this: 
"objectGUID" -> ";%y#uD_J�\�"��c�"

I read that it is possible to base-encode the objectGUID in OpenAM for SAML-requests. So my question is, whether it is possible to have a similar solution for an OAuth2 setup? Or maybe there are other workarounds to get a valid objectGUID in Java from OpenAM without accessing the Active Directory directly.

Thanks in advance